# MySQL - count only one distinct value from join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join, distinct

I have 5 tables.

```
auction, seller , auction_person,  person_company, quote
```

So for example, for one auction ( one seller) I have 4 person ( from same company ) in `auction_person`, but not all person have access to quote.

```
auction_person
---------------
id, auction, seller, person, person_company, can_quote
-----------------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | 1|    1  |   3           |    1
2   | 1      | 1|    2  |   3           |    0
3   | 1      | 1|    3  |   3           |    1
4   | 1      | 1|    4  |   3           |    1
```

And in `quote` table I have something like this

```
quote
------------
id,auction_person, auction, price,send_back, accepted
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 1      | 5$   | 1   | 0
1  | 4            | 1      | 2$   | 0   | 0
```

Some person quoted, some not, and some quotes are send_back but still not accepted.

I need

```
   1. COUNT(quote)  WHERE send_back = 1
   2. COUNT(accepted) WHERE send_back = 1
   3. COUNT(auction) 
WHERE seller = 1
```

BUT no matter how many contact persons per company are invited, quoted send_back, it should always count as one.

So If seller ( id = 1 ) invite 4 person from one company ( seller_id = 1 ), and for example 3 person have quoted ( 2 send_back, and 1 not send_back ), result is searched for company and should be like this.

```
auction   = 1
send_back = 1
accepted  = 0
```

Can this be done in only ONE query?

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand, what your questions ?

your need and your result is not same

```
what criteria of :
auction   = 1  = COUNT(quote)  WHERE send_back = 1
send_back = 1  = COUNT(send_back)  WHERE send_back = 1
accepted  = 0  = COUNT(accepted) WHERE send_back = 1



Select  Sum(Case    When IsNull(send_back, 0) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as auction,
        Sum(Case    When IsNull(send_back, 0) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as send_back,
        Sum(Case    When IsNull(accepted, 0) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) as accepted
from #auction_person a
Left Join #quote b
    On b.auction = a.auction
    And b.Auction_Person = a.Person
WHERE seller = 1
```